# How can I sort a column in excel ignoring leading characters?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a column in Excel with entries like

```
TI/303
BA/045
BA/009
AB/123
```

I would like to sort it by the numbers ignoring the first three characters like

```
BA/009
BA/045
AB/123
TI/303
```

How can I achieve such a custom sorting in Excel?

Answer (score 7):

Use a "helper" column........with your data in column **A**, in **B1** enter:

`=--MID(A1,4,9999)`  and copy down

Then sort cols **A** & **B** by **B**.

Comment: That's what I do. @Gary Is there another way to do this?

Comment: You could create a **macro** to do the same type of logic..............this would avoid the need for a "helper column"

Answer (score 0):

An addition to Gary's solution,

=Mid(A1,SEARCH("/",A1)+1,999)

will work for any length behind the slash (just in case someone else finds that helpful)